# Machine learning algorithms for interpreting Companies brand/s logo/s

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, machine-learning-model, computer-vision, image-recognition

https://www.google.com/search?q=Company+brand+logos&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=isnv&sxsrf=ALeKk0218I-1fMd-hNXX_fAF8_fu6EOotA:1600348128111&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinlcWtofDrAhVAyjgGHZcYAhgQ_AUoAXoECA4QAQ&biw=360&bih=592&dpr=2

https://www.google.com/search?q=Company+brand+logos&source=lmns&bih=592&biw=360&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=isnv&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNyJS8o_DrAhXFoUsFHUsWCeoQ_AUoAHoECAAQAw

Can Machine learning algorithms with companies brand/s logo/s as input images dataset interpret & give information about the company, products & services ?

Input :

Logo images format : gif, jpg,tiff.

Example : Intel logo image.

Output :

Website : intel.com

Products & Services :

Integrated Chips manufacturers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Very likely no!**

Machine learning algorithms aren't magic, they cannot see or find stuff that is not there.

We know for a fact that some trends and hints exist that link a companies exterior communication to it's industry e.g. social media companies like blue logos (think Twitter, Facebook, linkedin, etc.).

However for the most part logos, brand names, etc. do not have a structured way that ties them to such a specific information such as website-url, products and services.

Practically you will also have a huge problem gathering training material. This is a supervised image recognition problem which means that you would need hundreds/thousands of examples were images are correctly tagged with the information to train your model.

Given that a lot of industries do not even have that many brand names this will be near impossible.

**Alternatives?**

If all you want to do is identify the proper information about a company you could use ML to systematically crawl and gather that information from wikipedia or a companies website.

However that time and money is properly better spend on buying access to one of many, many company databases that already exist.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can Machine learning algorithms take input dataset as animated gifs images?. I mean can animated company brand Logo gifs assist in this regard?

Comment: Animated gifs can be easily used as input data but they still would not help in your goal. You would need a large amount of already annotated gifs to use for the training, I do not think such a training repertoire exists or can be created manually by just one person. And finally I do not think it overcomes the core problem: there likely isn't a strong relation between logos, corporate design and the sort of hard facts you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Basically in machine learning, you can't take a dataset and want to "find any info". You have to specify which kind of info you want. In your case, you could do a complete model trying to predict, using the logo as entry, if the company is recent or old for example. Here you defined your problem. Then you'll need training data, so you'll either have to specify yourself for a huge amount of logo, if the company is old or not, and then your model has some basis to learn, or find a way to automate this process (like browse logos and automatically find the date of creation of the firm to create the training data). This problem is a Classification problem.

You can also make Clustering, which would be for example giving the model some logos, and ask it to make groups of logos having the same global look.

Wathever your need is, you have to define it clearly so as your algorithm trains in this goal. You cannot just say "give me some informations about the company, the product"

Comment: Thanks for the information provided.